# Problema al registrar datos en java web usando jsp servlets

Tags: java, netbeans, jsp, servlets, maven

Hola buen día estoy tratando de hacer un registrar en java usando `netbeans` con `jsp`, `servlets` aplicando `dao` además el proyecto web esta con `maven` y se ejecuta con el servidor `glassfish`.

Tengo mi `jsp` llamado registrarCliente.jsp:

```
<h1>Registrar Cliente</h1>
    <form method="post" action="ServletCliente">
        <input type="hidden" name="accion" value="registrar">
        <input type="text" name="usuario" placeholder="Ingrese Usuario" />
        <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Ingrese contraseña" />
        <input type="text" name="nombres" placeholder="Ingrese Nombres" />
        <input type="text" name="apellidos" placeholder="Ingrese Apellidos" />
        <input type="text" name="dni" placeholder="Ingrese Dni" />
        <input type="email" name="correo" placeholder="Ingrese Email" />

        <input type="submit" value="Registrar" />
    </form>
```

Como ven tiene un input de tipo hidden de nombre accion y valor registrar.

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    String accion = request.getParameter("accion");
    if(accion.equals("registrar")){
        this.registrarCliente(request, response);
    }
}

private void registrarCliente(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) 
        throws ServletException, IOException{

    Cliente cliente = new Cliente();
    cliente.setUsuario(request.getParameter("usuario"));
    cliente.setContraseña(request.getParameter("pass"));
    cliente.setNombres(request.getParameter("nombres"));
    cliente.setApellidos(request.getParameter("apellidos"));
    cliente.setDni(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("dni")));
    cliente.setCorreo(request.getParameter("correo"));

    ClienteDao clienteDao = new ClienteDaoImpl();
    boolean resultado = clienteDao.registrarCliente(cliente);

    if(resultado){
        response.sendRedirect("exito.jsp");
    }else{
        response.sendRedirect("error.jsp");
    }
}
```

Pero al mandar los valores al `servlet` me aparece este error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y no se el porque. Esto me aparece en consola:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Código del registrarCliente en la clase ClienteDaoImpl:

```
public boolean registrarCliente(Cliente cliente) {
    try{
        Connection con = conexion.conectaBD();
        PreparedStatement cs = con.prepareStatement("insert into clientes(usuario,contraseña,"
                + "nombres,apellidos,dni,correo) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        cs.setString(1, cliente.getUsuario());
        cs.setString(2, cliente.getContraseña());
        cs.setString(3, cliente.getNombres());
        cs.setString(4, cliente.getApellidos());
        cs.setInt(5, cliente.getDni());
        cs.setString(6, cliente.getCorreo());
        cs.executeUpdate();
        return true;
    }catch(SQLException ex){
        return false;
    }
}
```

También al hacer un debug sólo llega hasta esta parte del código:

```
if(accion.equals("registrar")){
        this.registrarCliente(request, response);
    }
```

Lo valida y se detiene ya no avanza hasta el método.

Comment: Podrías subir lo que te aparece en consola? Porque lo que menciona es que hay un valor que es nulo. Tendrías que comprobar cuál de esos atributos (nombres, apellidos, dni, correo, etc) te está generando error por ser nulo.

Comment: Busca el log en los logs del servidor. Ahí viene más detallado el error.

Comment: Hola amigos gracias por responder acabo de actualizar la pregunta agregando lo que me aparece en consola. E verificado por medio de un debug que los valores de los input si llegan al servlet pero el problema persiste

Comment: Como dice el log, el error está en el objeto ClienteDaoImpl, en el método registrarCliente(...) en la línea 21... vas a tener que poner el código del método para determinar que variable tiene valor NULL.

Comment: Este es el código del método registrarCliente:
public boolean registrarCliente(Cliente cliente) {
try{Connection con = conexion.conectaBD();
PreparedStatement cs = con.prepareStatement("insert into clientes(usuario,contraseña,"+ "nombres,apellidos,dni,correo) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)");
cs.setString(1, cliente.getUsuario());
cs.setString(2, cliente.getContraseña());
cs.setString(3, cliente.getNombres());
cs.setString(4, cliente.getApellidos());
cs.setInt(5, cliente.getDni());
cs.setString(6, cliente.getCorreo());
cs.executeUpdate();
return true;
}catch(SQLException ex)
{return false;}}

Comment: Añade el código a tu pregunta original. Para la ejecución en ClienteDaoImpl antes de ejecutar la sentencia e intenta ejecutarla "a mano". También saca el error - en el catch no haces nada, solo devuelves false.

Comment: Ademas agrega el numero de las lineas de código para el método registrarCliente(Cliente cliente), de lo contrario no de puede determinar correctamente el punto del error.

Comment: En la consola veo que el driver `JDBC` que estas utilizando esta obsoleto. Intenta descargarte el driver `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`

Comment: Muchas gracias a todos por sus respuestas recién acabo de solucionar el problema el cual estaba en el jsp. Me di cuenta que el valor de la contraseña pasaba null o vacío lo que hice fue cambiar el valor de name que estaba como "contraseña" por "clave" de igual manera en el servlet. Y así se logro registrar los datos. No se que problema habrá con la palabra "contraseña" también lo había intentado con la palabra "password" pero nada y eso que esta con charset="utf-8"

Answer (score 0):

Tu método **"registrarCliente"** no está retornando ningún valor, dentro de tu método define una variable tipo `boolean` y haz que devuelva ese valor. Intenta hacer esto.

```
public static boolean registrarCliente(Cliente cliente) {
boolean resp = false;
try{
    Connection con = conexion.conectaBD();
    PreparedStatement cs = con.prepareStatement("insert into clientes(usuario,contraseña,"
            + "nombres,apellidos,dni,correo) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)");
    cs.setString(1, cliente.getUsuario());
    cs.setString(2, cliente.getContraseña());
    cs.setString(3, cliente.getNombres());
    cs.setString(4, cliente.getApellidos());
    cs.setInt(5, cliente.getDni());
    cs.setString(6, cliente.getCorreo());
    int i = cs.executeUpdate(); // Si se ejecuta da valor 1 caso contrario es 0
    if(i == 1){
        resp = true;
    }
}catch(SQLException ex){
    resp = false;
    System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
}
return resp;
}
```

En el **Servlet** llama al método de la siguiente manera.

```
boolean resultado = clienteDao.registrarCliente(cliente);
if(resultado){
    response.sendRedirect("exito.jsp");
}else{
    response.sendRedirect("error.jsp"); 
}
```

El código no está compilado, pero tu puedes probarlo.